# How to seperate comma seperated values in List Array as a single Datarow

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, string, ado.net

My List array **List lines = new List();** contains below data:

```
MSC,1
MSC,2
MSC,3
```

Now i want to use column 1 as Xaxis and column 2 as Yaxis in chart. Below is my code i did try but its not working properly. Please help me correct this code.

```
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
        dt.Columns.Add("Counter", typeof(string));
        foreach (string str in lines)
        {
            DataRow r1 = dt.NewRow();  
            r1[0] = str;   // Assign values 
            dt.Rows.Add(r1);             
            DataRow r2 = dt.NewRow();  
            r1[1] = str;   // Assign values 
            dt.Rows.Add(r2);            

        }
```

My output is given below. I want these 1,2,3 and 4 values on y-axis.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `string.Split` method for each line split the content by `,`. After that, use any item and define a new row on the DataTable. For sample:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
dt.Columns.Add("Counter", typeof(string));
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var values = line.Split(new[] { ',' });
    DataRow row = dt.NewRow();  
    row["Name"] = values[0];
    row["Counter"] = values[1];
    dt.Rows.Add(row);
}
```